# How can I convert the special character by using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I have problems using `mysqli_real_escape_string` for storing text in `PHP`

**The text I would like to store:**

```
tesing%2Bsmaple%2Bid
```

**Then I use the method:**

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query['ID']);
echo $id;
```

The text changes to:

```
tesing+smaple+id
```

Why does the text change and what should I do if I don't want it to automatically convert it?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars converts characters with special meaning in HTML into entities. That is essential if you have some text that you want to insert into an HTML document (as it stops, for instance, characters such as < being treated as the start of tags, and protects against XSS).

mysql_real_escape_string converts characters with special meaning in MySQL SQL queries into escapes. This allows you to insert arbitrary strings into a MySQL database safely (protecting against errors and injection. There are, however, better ways to do the same thing.

try this:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($query['ID']));
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to `base64_encode()` the value before storing and `base64_decode()` it while pulling from database. You wont loose any information :)

```
<?php
$myvar = "tesing%2Bsmaple%2Bid";
$vartostore = base64_encode($myvar);
echo $vartostore;
$varfromdb = base64_decode($vartostore);
echo $varfromdb;
```